# The proof of an upper bound of a union of multiple sets?

Tags: probability, inequality, inclusion-exclusion

$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) \leq \min _k\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}\left(A_i\right)-\sum_{i: i \neq k} \mathbb{P}\left(A_i \cap A_k\right)\right\}$

I think mathematical induction is provable, but when k=n, I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: $\le \min_k$ is equivalent to $\le$ for all $k$.